# Convert port to :port of type string in Golang

Tags: linux, webserver, go

How do you convert a port inputted as a int by the user to a string of type ":port" (ie, it should have a ':' in front of it and should be converted to string). The output has to be feed to http.ListenAndServe().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), handler); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: First, I would not get in the habit of using `fmt` for conversions. Using `reflect`, it can be expensive. Since `fmt` functions take `interface{}`, "80" is also valid, which produces `:%!d(string=80)`.

Answer (score 4):

You could (ought to?) use [`net.JoinHostPort(host, port string)`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#JoinHostPort).

Convert `port` to a string with [`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa).

It'll also handle the case where the host part contains a colon: "host:port".  Feed that directly to `ListenAndServe`.

Here is some sample code:

```
host := ""
port := 80
str := net.JoinHostPort(host, strconv.Itoa(port))
fmt.Printf("host:port = '%s'", str)
// Can be fed directly to: 
// http.ListenAndServe(str, nil)
```

The above can be run on a playground: https://play.golang.org/p/AL3obKjwcjZ

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strconv.Itoa()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa)

Something like:

```
p := strconv.Itoa(port)
addr := ":" + p
// or for localhost only
// addr := "localhost:" + p
```

Then

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't help... I have tried it.There is some problem with slices...
btw.. I'm a beginner to Go... Don't know much at this time...